# Calculating magnitude of current provided by a voltage source

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, voltage-source

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flm5Tl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A couple of days ago I attended an exam where I was asked to calculate

1. Voltage at node A;
2. Voltage at node B;
3. Current provided by the voltage source.

Using node analysis I managed to find voltages at node A and B (I got 12.13 for VA and 5.84 for VB), but I am still having difficulties in finding the current provided by the voltage source (V1 in the circuit). How can I calculate the magnitude of this current?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the voltage at B, and the resistance R3. From Ohm's you can calculate the current through R3. The current source takes 10mA of that current, and from KCL we know that the voltage source takes the rest. I calculate 9.46mA from voltage source.